# Boot hangs on line "xor: measuring software checksum speed"

Tags: boot, virtualbox, vagrant

Lately when booting Ubuntu 20.04, roughly every 2 out of 3 times the machine hangs on this line:

`xor: measuring software checksum speed`.

I'm running it as a guest machine on Windows 11 via Vagrant with a VirtualBox provider. That setup very well may have something to do with it or it may not. I'm not sure as I have found next to no information online regarding this in any context. Since troubleshooting that setup is possibly beyond the scope of this site, I'm content with limiting my question to Ubuntu.

What could cause Ubuntu to stall on that line during boot?

Comment: Maybe try blacklisting the xor module? It seems it is only needed for software RAID, which you're most likely not using in the VM anyway.